# Python; the most performant way to implement element-wise vector multiplication

Tags: python, performance

I need function-aggregator, which would reduce two lists to one total number. 'Items' is supposed to be vector of Booleans.

So, I wrote these functions:

```
def element_wise_multiplication(weights, items):
    return map(lambda x, y: x * y, weights, items)

def total(weights, items):
    return sum(element_wise_multiplication(weights, items))
```

They look OK to me, but the problem is that profiler showed that the line with lambda in it is responsible for 95% of runtime, so its performance is pretty much unacceptable.

What is the most efficient way to implement it?

P.S. I am aware of NumPy's arrays, but I would like to use PyPy  on this one. Or is using it not worth it in this case?

Comment: On PyPy you would be much better off just writing it in a simple loop. Plus your code would be more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take care of that with a generator like so:

```
from itertools import izip
value = sum((x * y) for x, y in izip(weights, items))
```

`izip` accomplishes the same thing as the built-in `zip`, but without the memory overhead.

Comment: The memory overhead is higher, of course, but... `value = sum([(x * y) for x, y in izip(weights, items)])` is actually faster :)

Comment: This gave 24% optimization. Any chance to push it even further?

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes thanks! 47% optimization. That's more like it)

Answer (score 2):

Although you mention not wishing to use numpy in this case, it may be worth looking at the speed differences.

The best non-numpy solution appears to be a generator using izip which marginally outperforms zip.

```
    In [31]: %timeit sum(x*y for x,y in zip(weights,items))
    10000 loops, best of 3: 158 us per loop

    In [32]: %timeit sum(x*y for x,y in izip(weights,items))
    10000 loops, best of 3: 125 us per loop
```

However when we use the numpy arrays we get:

```
    In [33]: %timeit (np_weights,np_items).sum()
    100000 loops, best of 3: 9.08 us per loop
```

The numpy solution is a full 14 times faster. If this is really a bottleneck in your code then numpy is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

try just this:

```
def total(weights, items):
   return sum (x * y for x, y in zip(weights, items))
```